# How to convert .dex to .jar in mac osx

Tags: android

I'm using Mac OSX(10.7) and trying to extract java file from a android apk. So i downloaded apk and then copied dex2jar file from 
http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

After extracting dex file from apk(classes.dex), i had unzipped dex2jar and opened termial changed directory path to  dex2jar and executed as below

```
my-MacBook-Pro:dex2jar-0.0.9.11 my$ **dex2jar.sh classes.dex**
```

but it says ****-bash: dex2jar.sh: command not found****

I checked in directory and dex2jar.sh is present. What is the mistake i'm doing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try ./dex2jar.sh .  My guess is this directory isn't in your $PATH, so your system doesn't know where to find it.  The ./ will tell it to look in the current directory.

Comment: if it's not set as executable, you need to execute the following command first: 

`chmod +x ./dex2jar.sh`

Comment: And maybe also for the ./d2j_invoke.sh

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me is to add an alias to my `.bash_profile`.

I renamed and move the `dex2jar-*` folder to my `/usr/local/bin/dex2jar` directory.

Then I added the following line to my `.bash_profile` file:

```
alias dex2jar='sh /usr/local/bin/dex2jar/d2j-dex2jar.sh'
```

Remember to run the following command to update environment variables:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

After all that is setup then I can simply convert files with:

```
$ dex2jar file
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like this:

> "C:\Users...\dex\Dex2jar.java" classes.dex

Just write full PATH from command line and if there are whitespaces surround uri path with ""